# How to connect mysqlp express 2005 to my website?

Tags: php, sql-server, ssms, management-studio-express

Is it possible that I can connect SQL Server Management Studio Express to
my website?

Please help me or provide me a link me to any article detailing the process.

Comment: Try by creating a DSN and connect it to Php by PDO
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php